# Jboss cannot find class in jar, but finds another in same jar?

Tags: class, jar, jboss, loading

I try to deploy an application on the jboss 4.2.3 GA server. It looks as if Jboss cannot find a class in a jar, but finds another in same jar. I suppose it only looks this, and it cannot find the jar at all. But then, why not?

In the main servlet `RegisterServlet` is this statement:

```
dispManager = (DispatcherManager)DispatcherManagerFactory.getDispatcherManager();
```

The class `DispatcherManagerImpl` is only instantiated in `DispatcherManagerFactory`, nowhere else.
`DispatcherManagerFactory` and `DispatcherManagerImpl` exist in a jar file, that is in my WEB-INF/lib library. And only there, not in a Jboss server lib.

I get a ClassNotFoundException on class `DispatcherManagerImpl`. 
How is it possible that I did not get a ClassNotFoundException on `DispatcherManagerFactory` first?

I googled a lot about jboss classloading, but a jar file in WEB-INF/lib should be found, I think.

Structure of myApp:

```
myApp.ear
    META-INF 
        application.xml
        jboss-app.xml
    MANIFEST.MF
myApp.war
    META-INF
    WEB-INF
        classes
        lib     
            *.jar   
        licenses
        jboss-web.xml
        web.xml
        ...
```

Contents of application.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE application PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD J2EE Application   1.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/application_1_3.dtd">
<application id="myApp-059-20091104-1530">
<display-name>myApp-059-20091104-1530</display-name>
<module id="WebModule_1212992751021">
    <web>
        <web-uri>myApp.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>myApp</context-root>
    </web>
</module>
<security-role id="SecurityRole_1210074998462">
    <description>User who can use the administration console</description>
    <role-name>myAppBeheerder</role-name>
</security-role>
</application>
```

Contents of jboss-app.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-app PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD J2EE Application .3V2//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-app_4_2.dtd">
<jboss-app>
  <loader-repository>myApp:loader=myAppRepository</loader-repository>
</jboss-app>
```

Contents of jboss-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
<resource-ref>  
<res-ref-name>jdbc/duplodb</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<jndi-name>java:/duplodb</jndi-name>
</resource-ref>
 </jboss-web>
```

Contents of web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
<display-name>myApp</display-name>

<description>This Web settings implements the Import functionality.</description>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>registerservlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>registerservlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>nl.nn.lc.duploimport.RegisterServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
    <param-name>SplitterRegisteredObjectName</param-name>
    <param-value>ibis4duplo-ponsfilesplitter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>WorkerRegisteredObjectName</param-name>
        <param-value>ibis4duplo-ponsmutationworker</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>autoStart</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
<load-on-startup>0</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>registerservlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/RegisterServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_1211270252323">
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/duplodb</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Application</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>SecurityDuploImport</web-resource-name>
        <description></description>
        <url-pattern>
        /*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>
        GET</http-method>
        <http-method>
        POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <description></description>
        <role-name>DuploImportBeheerder</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>duploimport</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <description>User who can use the Duplo IMport administration console</description>
    <role-name>DuploImportBeheerder</role-name>
</security-role>   
</web-app>
```

In `RegisterServlet.init()` I added a print of the Stacktrace:

```
public void init() throws ServletException {
        super.init();
        try {
            dispManager = (DispatcherManager)DispatcherManagerFactory.getDispatcherManager();   
            registerImportProxy();
            logRegServlet.debug(strSuccessMessage);
        } catch (DispatcherException e) {
            logRegServlet.error(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }
    }
```

The full StackTrace is

```
15:33:54,808 INFO  [STDOUT] nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.Disp
atcherManagerImpl
15:33:54,808 INFO  [STDOUT]     at nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerImpl.getInstance(DispatcherManagerImpl.java:65)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerFactory.getDispatcherManager(DispatcherManagerFactory.java:19)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at nl.nn.lc.duploimport.RegisterServlet.init(Unknown Source)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1048)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:950)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4122)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4421)
15:33:54,809 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeployInternal(TomcatDeployment.java:367)
15:33:54,810 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.deployers.TomcatDeployment.performDeploy(TomcatDeployment.java:146)
15:33:54,810 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.deployers.AbstractWarDeployment.start(AbstractWarDeployment.java:460)
15:33:54,810 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.startModule(WebModule.java:118)
15:33:54,810 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.web.deployers.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:96)
15:33:54,810 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
15:33:54,811 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
15:33:54,813 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
15:33:54,815 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
15:33:54,817 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157)
15:33:54,819 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96)
15:33:54,821 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88)
15:33:54,823 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:264)
15:33:54,823 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:668)
15:33:54,823 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceProxy.invoke(ServiceProxy.java:206)
15:33:54,824 INFO  [STDOUT]     at $Proxy36.start(Unknown Source)
15:33:54,824 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:42)
15:33:54,824 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.StartStopLifecycleAction.installAction(StartStopLifecycleAction.java:37)
15:33:54,824 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.SimpleControllerContextAction.simpleInstallAction(SimpleControllerContextAction.java
:62)
15:33:54,824 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.action.AccessControllerContextAction.install(AccessControllerContextAction.java:71)
15:33:54,825 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContextActions.install(AbstractControllerContextActions.java:51)
15:33:54,825 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
15:33:54,825 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.microcontainer.ServiceControllerContext.install(ServiceControllerContext.java:286)
15:33:54,825 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
15:33:54,826 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
15:33:54,826 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
15:33:54,827 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
15:33:54,827 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
15:33:54,827 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
15:33:54,827 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.doChange(ServiceController.java:688)
15:33:54,827 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.ServiceController.start(ServiceController.java:460)
15:33:54,838 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.start(ServiceDeployer.java:146)
15:33:54,843 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:104)
15:33:54,843 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.deployers.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:45)
15:33:54,843 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.internalDeploy(AbstractSimpleRealDeployer.java:62)
15:33:54,843 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.spi.deployer.helpers.AbstractRealDeployer.deploy(AbstractRealDeployer.java:50)
15:33:54,854 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployerWrapper.deploy(DeployerWrapper.java:171)
15:33:54,857 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doDeploy(DeployersImpl.java:1439)
15:33:54,857 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1157)
15:33:54,857 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1178)
15:33:54,857 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.doInstallParentFirst(DeployersImpl.java:1210)
15:33:54,858 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.install(DeployersImpl.java:1098)
15:33:54,859 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractControllerContext.install(AbstractControllerContext.java:348)
15:33:54,859 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.install(AbstractController.java:1598)
15:33:54,859 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.incrementState(AbstractController.java:934)
15:33:54,859 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:1062)
15:33:54,860 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.resolveContexts(AbstractController.java:984)
15:33:54,860 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:822)
15:33:54,861 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.dependency.plugins.AbstractController.change(AbstractController.java:553)
15:33:54,861 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.process(DeployersImpl.java:781)
15:33:54,874 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.process(MainDeployerImpl.java:545)
15:33:54,874 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.loadProfile(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:304)
15:33:54,874 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.system.server.profileservice.ProfileServiceBootstrap.start(ProfileServiceBootstrap.java:205)
15:33:54,874 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.bootstrap.AbstractServerImpl.start(AbstractServerImpl.java:405)
15:33:54,875 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.Main.boot(Main.java:209)
15:33:54,875 INFO  [STDOUT]     at org.jboss.Main$1.run(Main.java:547)
15:33:54,875 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
15:33:54,876 INFO  [STDOUT] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerImpl
15:33:54,876 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
15:33:54,876 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
15:33:54,876 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
15:33:54,876 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
15:33:54,877 INFO  [STDOUT]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
15:33:54,890 INFO  [STDOUT]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
15:33:54,890 INFO  [STDOUT]     at nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerImpl.getInstance(DispatcherManagerImpl.java:52)
15:33:54,890 INFO  [STDOUT]     ... 64 more
```

After putting `-verbose:class` to my java command in run.bat, it seems that both classes are loaded:
`[Loaded nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerFactory from jar:file:/C:/jboss/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/myApp/deploy/myApp.ear!/myApp.war]
[Loaded nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManager from jar:file:/C:/jboss/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/myApp/deploy/myApp.ear!/myApp.war]
[Loaded nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.DispatcherManagerImpl from jar:file:/C:/jboss/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/myApp/deploy/myApp.ear!/myApp.war]
[Loaded nl.nn.adapterframework.dispatcher.RequestProcessorException from jar:file:/C:/jboss/jboss-5.0.0.GA/server/myApp/deploy/myApp.ear!/myApp.war]`

The stack trace says that `DispatcherManagerImpl` is not found when `DispatcherManagerImpl.getInstance()` is executed. That seems very strange to me. How can a class not be found at line 65 of the very same class?

Comment: basic stuff: did you verify that the jar is complete (open it like a zip file or in an ide)?

Comment: could you double check if the *.jar is not included twice in the classpath, for example also in *.ear libraries, if any?

Comment: Yes, I checked that: both classes are in that jar, and only there. And there is only one version of the jar.

Comment: Talking about basic stuff: I think that the jar is not on the classpath at all, and the error message is just confusing. But is placing it on WEB-INF/lib not sufficient?

Comment: I tried to deploy the application to Jboss 5.0.0. Now it first gave `ClassCastException`, because in my WEB-INF/lib are some jar's that are also present in server/myApp/lib. At first, this was good news, because it means the server is aware of the jars in WEB-INF/lib. So I removed the offending jars, but then I got that same `ClassNotFoundException` on `DispatcherManagerImpl` again.
Any suggestion on this is very welcome.

Comment: Another addition: 
The jar contains:
`DispatcherManager.class`
`DispatcherManagerImpl.class`
`RequestProcessor.class` (and a few other classes).
If I remove the jar completely, I cannot deploy the app at all, I get `ClassNotFoundException` on `RequestProcessor.class`.
If I add the jar, I get the `ClassNotFoundException` on `DispatcherManagerImpl`, but that only appears in the log of my application. The app seems to deploy, but cannot be used.

Comment: Please edit the post to provide the full ClassNotFoundException message.

Comment: @cyates, I added the StackTrace for this exception.

Comment: The `RegisterServlet` catches the exception and only logs the message. So the fact that the URL doesn't work is not directly caused by this exception. It is problably caused by some jboss setting not being correct.

Comment: I added `-verbose:class` to the java command in run.bat, but the output indicates, that both classes are in fact loaded, see post.
The fact that the URL not works seems to be caused by a <security-constraint> in the web.xml. When I commented that out, the URL worked.